# To check whether elements of a list is a subset of elements of another list

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here I am trying to check whether elements of 'b' that are [1,3],[1,5],[3,7],[5,7],[6,9],[8,10] are subsets of elements of 'a' that are [1,3,5,7] and [6,8,9,10].
If any element of b is subset of any element of a then it gets removed from b.

```
     a = [[1, 3, 5, 7],[6, 8, 9, 10]]
     b = [[1, 3], [1, 5],[10, 11],[6, 9],[8, 10]]
```

If any element of 'b' is subset of any element of 'a' then it gets removed from b.
That means the new b should be :-

```
     b = [[10,11]]
```

Comment: Very nice. What did you try?

Comment: You're question isn't very clear at least to me. Do you mean any array in b that is one of the pairs producible from a

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review our SO Question Checklist to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer. Please paste a minimal, complete, and verifiable example of the code you have already tried.

Comment: yes, any array of 2 elements in b is made from any array of 4 elements in a.

Answer (score 0):

If you want set operations, use python's [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) data type, which has a `issubset()` method.

```
b = [x for x in b if not any(set(x).issubset(y) for y in a)]
```